# Is it possible to get SQL Server session id with LINQ?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq, session

There are spid function in sql server. Is it possible to get value of that session as well as other values like loginname with LINQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (comes from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189535.aspx)

```
SELECT @@SPID AS 'ID', SYSTEM_USER AS 'Login Name', USER AS 'User Name'
```

Something along the lines of this should work with linq, provided you have the proper object setup to take the incoming data (this is not exact as I am not that familiar with SPID and have not tested this)

```
public class systemData
{
  int spid;
  string loginname;
  string username;
}
IEnumerable<systemData> results = db.ExecuteQuery<systemData>("SELECT @@SPID AS 'ID', SYSTEM_USER AS 'Login Name', USER AS 'User Name'");
```